# `gulp serve` gets stuck on "[BS] Reloading files that match: *.js"

Tags: gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeogurt

I'm creating a site with yeoman using the yeogurt generator. After running `yo yeogurt` and going through the options, it finishes successfully with no errors and tells me I should now run `gulp serve`. However, when I do, it gets stuck on the last line of the output below:

```
[16:08:16] Using gulpfile ~/myproj/gulpfile.js
[16:08:16] Starting 'imagemin'...
[16:08:16] Starting 'copy'...
[16:08:16] Starting 'jade'...
[16:08:16] Starting 'sass'...
[16:08:16] Finished 'sass' after 124 ms
[16:08:16] Starting 'browserify'...
[16:08:16] Starting 'browserSync'...
[16:08:16] Finished 'browserSync' after 9.69 ms
[16:08:16] Starting 'watch'...
[16:08:16] Finished 'watch' after 39 ms
[16:08:16] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[16:08:16] Finished 'imagemin' after 355 ms
[BS] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/./
    External: http://192.168.1.115:3000/./
 -----------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.115:3001
 -----------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: tmp
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[16:08:16] Finished 'jade' after 492 ms
[16:08:16] Finished 'copy' after 495 ms
[BS] 1 file changed (main.css)
[16:08:17] 715847 bytes written (0.71 seconds)
./src/_scripts/main.js was browserified: 0.754s
[BS] Reloading files that match: *.js
```

I'm having a hard time tracking down this error.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: it wasn't 'stuck' at all. It had run successfully and the server was active on port `3000`. I was just used to Gulp opening the browser window for you when the server starts, but with Yeogurt, it doesn't do that unless you add the `--open` flag.